# mysql performance on fulltext on MATCH multiple columns vs MATCH single column

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, match

I am trying to know efficient way on implementing full text search on my table. Say I have a table with fields,

```
FName LName FullName    webId   phoneNumber office searchField
bill  gates bill gates  bgates  1324343324  USA    bill.gates.bill gates.bgates.1324343324
steve jobs  steve jobs  sjobs   3453454646  UK     steve.jobs.steve jobs.sjobs.3453454646
steve gates steve gates sgates  3453451234  AUS    steve.gates.steve gates.sgates.3453451234
```

The search term could match an individual column, or it might be combination of keywords that could match multiple columns.

Would it be better to implement FULLTEXT index on searchField column (or) individual columns and then query as

`select * from TABLENAME where MATCH(FName,LName,webId,phoneNumber) AGAINST ('$search_str')`

or`select * from TABLENAME where MATCH(searchField) AGAINST ('$search_str')`

Which one is better implementation?